# Disable Autocomplete(IE) in VIsual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, browser

I have a very simple C#-Form in which there is just a Web browser opening a website. When i execute the code and the browser loads the desired website i always get an warning which looks like this

[image]

I do not want to have to touch the website or the browser for it, is there a way to solve this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this line:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```